# Custom display label for grouped_collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following `grouped_collection_select` in my View:

```
<%= grouped_collection_select(:classroom, :course_id, @classrooms, :courses, :name, :id, :name) %>
```

How do I customize the display label such that it is the concatenation of 2 attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grouped_collection_select` takes a method-name as the parameter for the label. Labels are generated by calling that method on each object in the collection.

In your example, the method is called `:name` but you could create a method on your `Classroom` class that contains the two attributes you want eg:

```
# totally made up - use whatever attributes and method-name you want
def name_and_location
  [name, location].join(': ')
end
```

then just use it in the collection-select:

```
<%= grouped_collection_select(:classroom, :course_id, @classrooms, :courses, :name_and_location, :id, :name) %>
```

Note: the above example is for the group-label... hut you can equally well do the same for the individual item-label, just use the last parameter and put the method on your `Course` model instead.